# SQL: Order by column desc in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, max

I have this SQL (SQLite database), which correctly gets  the most recent message from the messages table grouped by conversation_id where the message has a conversation id other than 'none'.

```
SELECT * from messages 
WHERE _id
IN ( 
   SELECT MAX(_id)
   FROM messages
   WHERE conversation_id != 'none'
   GROUP BY conversation_id
   )
```

However, I'd like to use an "unseenreplies" column in the conversation table (which has a number count of the unseen replies for this conversation) to *order* the messages that come out.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT * from messages
WHERE _id IN 
(
   SELECT max(_id) from messages m
   JOIN conversations c 
   ON m.conversation_id = c.cid ORDER BY 
   c.unseenreplies DESC 
   where m.conversation_id != 'none' group by m.conversation_id )
```

But I get a syntax error near the 'where' clause.

Just by way of explanation 'conversation id' isn't the primary key of the conversation table, but an identifier string.

How can I fix this? Is my approach with the JOIN way off?

Comment: Mahmoud gave you a query that will work.  The problem you had was the sequence of your clauses.  You had the order by clause before the where clause.  Order by clauses are almost always the final clause of a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` them instead of the `IN` predicate:

```
SELECT * 
from messages AS m1
INNER JOIN conversations c1 ON m1.conversation_id = c1.cid
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT max(_id) AS MAxId 
   from messages m
   where m.conversation_id != 'none' 
   GROUP BY m.conversation_id 
) AS m2 ON m1._id = m2.MaxId
ORDER BY  c.unseenreplies DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove the `in` statement to get this to work.  The key is the join between `conversations` and `messages`:

```
SELECT m.*
from messages m join
     conversations c
     on m.conversation_id = c.cid
WHERE _id
IN ( 
   SELECT MAX(_id)
   FROM messages
   WHERE conversation_id != 'none'
   GROUP BY conversation_id
   ) 
order by c.unseenreplies desc
```

Also, notice that this only pulls the columns from the `messages` table instead of all the columns.